# How can I let Haskell know I don't care what a generic's type is?

Tags: haskell, generics, typeclass

I'm working on some code deep in the bowels of an application and would like to make it generic w.r.t. some of the types it's using so I can mock the types for unit tests.

I'm trying to setup a type-class along the lines of:

```
class (Monad m) => SomeClass m a x d | m -> a where
  makeState :: x -> m (a x)
  open :: (a x) -> m (a d)
  use :: OtherArg -> (a d) -> m ()
  close :: (a d) -> m ()
```

where the `m` type-variable will be a monad (e.g. `IO`, `ST`), `a` will be some sort of wrapper type in the monad (e.g. `MVar`, `STRef`) and `x` will be known at compile-time, but I don't care about the type of `d` in the functions using the type-class, just in the type-class instance function implementations themselves.

Right now I'm just trying to get my types setup and it's erroring when I add the constraint to my functions, e.g.:

```
someFn :: (SomeClass m a Model d) => a d -> a Model -> T m ()
```

the compiler is complaining that `d` is ambiguous and won't let me get away without concretely specifying the type, meaning I won't be able to mock it.

I looked briefly at some language extensions and it seems like `RankNTypes` might be what I need but I'm not sure how to go about utilizing it.

Is this the right approach to accomplish what I'm trying to do, or should I be approaching it differently? (I wouldn't be surprised if I'm approaching it too OOPily as I've been working in Java a lot recently.)

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps it is enough make the fundep mad:

`class (Monad m) => SomeClass m a x d | m -> a d where`

Comment: Or `| m -> a, m a x -> d`?

Comment: @daniel-wagner Aha! I'd been messing with that a little bit but I guess I hadn't had the right combination -- yours did the trick, thanks!